# Tags: Koala vs Koala-gem

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

According to the [koala](/questions/tagged/koala) tag wiki it is targeting questions about the Ruby-on-Rails koala gem. It has 169 questions

So, the [koala-gem](/questions/tagged/koala-gem) (it does not have a tag wiki) is exactly identical (it has 8 questions, of which most also use the [koala](/questions/tagged/koala) tag).

I therefore propose to make [koala-gem](/questions/tagged/koala-gem) a synonym of [koala](/questions/tagged/koala)

Comment: If nobody chimes in with a reasonable objection, I'll do this later this evening. I can't see there being an objection to the synonym.

Answer (score 2):

I am the developer behind the new Koala language to which is referred earlier (http://blog.camilstaps.nl/2012/11/koala-announcement/)
As you can read there, this will be a language which can be used to program PIC microcontrollers.

However, this language will not reach a giant audience. For example, have a look at the - lower profile, in my opinion - [Jal](http://justanotherlanguage.org) language, which has the same purpose.

I will take care myself for a discussion group on Yahoo or something to help people with problems. For a smaller language, that's easier than this - great though - website.

Therefore, I do not see it necessary to reserve the Koala tag. By the way, if my language will gain territory and this site would become useful to my users, the pic-koala tag could be used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a programming language called [Koala](http://camilstaps.nl/2012/11/koala-announcement/), but it is not so extensively used to cause any tag clash, though.

I would merge the tags, and make [koala-gem](/questions/tagged/koala-gem) a synonym of [koala](/questions/tagged/koala).