# Remove tag score requirement for suggesting synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

When proposing a synonym one need to comply to:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

I agree with the *reputation requirement*: it makes sure that the user is aware of the (inner) workings of the site.

I suppose that this reasoning is similar to the *tag score requirement*: one needs to provide (s)he has knowledge about the tag.

But I do **not agree** with this second (tag score) requirement.

Without knowledge of the tag subject it is not a problem to detect synonyms (for most of the tags):

- [jpg vs jpeg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161969/tags-jpeg-vs-jpg): easy, both are almost the same: *jpg* is a file extension of JPEG, but we do not require a separate tag for each file extension of a JPEG file)
- [koala vs koala-gem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159493/tags-koala-vs-koala-gem): easy, *koala* is a Ruby gem (according to its [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/koala)) and thus is exactly the same as *koala-gem* (I am (now) aware that there is a language in development called koala, but [koala](/questions/tagged/koala) is not about that language)
- [make-the-corona-tag-synonym-of-coronasdk](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146064/make-the-corona-tag-synonym-of-coronasdk), both [corona](/questions/tagged/corona) and [coronasdk](/questions/tagged/coronasdk) wiki (excerpts) are exactly the same!
- [lots of singular vs plural synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsynonym-request%5D+plural): easy, I suppose that this does not require further details

All of these above requests (and there are loads more) can be done by a trusted user without any knowledge on the actual topics.

So, I do not really understand the *tag score requirement* and would propose to remove the *tag score requirement*.

Additional thought: If the moderators are afraid of misuse of the synonym request system, the *reputation requirement* could be increased instead, so only 'more responsible' users have the permission to propose a synonym (although I do not think it is necessary to increase the reputation requirement further).

**Edit**: [Daniel Fischer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/177145/daniel-fischer) came with an improved proposal: Low reputation users **keep** the *tag score requirement* and high reputation users do **not require** it. So low-reputation users are still able to suggest synonyms for the tags they have enough knowledge and high reputation users are trusted enough to suggest any tag synonym.

Comment: Requirement for suggesting a tag synonym (total rep >= 2500 + tag score >= 5) or (total rep >= 5000)? [or 10K, whatever]

Comment: @DanielFischer I do not understand your comment completely, but my proposal is to only keep the `total rep >= 2500` requirement (or any other reputation score). SO trusted users are able to provide synonyms for any tag.

Comment: My suggestion is to still require a tag score for users with not-so-much reputation, but allow users with higher reputation to suggest synonyms regardless of whether they have any participation in the concerned tags. So if you have less experience with the site, some experience with the tag is required, but if you have enough overall experience, you are trusted not to make [many] nonsensical synonym suggestions even if you have no particular experience in the tag. The numbers are of course open to discussion.

Comment: @DanielFischer ah! Good idea, I'll update the question

Comment: Or one could make it `total rep + C*tag score >= threshold`.

Comment: related (not a duplicate): [Does the tag synonym suggestion system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127459/165773) **"I've never seen a tag synonym created via the voting mechanism and I see [evidence](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Tag+merge+request%22%22) that the system isn't working to create synonyms without moderator intervention..."**